# A question in "record values"

Tags: probability

This is an example on the book, Probability Theory and Examples version 5, by Rick Durrett.

The model is the following. Let $X_1, X_2,...$ are i.i.d. with a distribution $F(x)$ that is continuous. $A_k = \{X_k > \sup_{j<k} X_j\}$.

To obtain the probability of $A_k$, we consider the following random permutation. Note that $P(X_j = X_k) = 0, j \neq k$. Let $Y_1^n > Y_2^n > ... > Y_n^n$ be the r.v. $X_1,...,X_n$ put into decreasing order and define a random permutation by $\pi_n(i) = j$ if $X_i = Y_j^n$. I understand the calculation of probability of $\pi_n$ by symmetry. But I have questions in the other statement.

[image]

1. Why $\pi_n \circ \sigma_n$ has the same distribution of $\pi_n$? I think the reason is that the random permutation is always derived from sorting a sequence so that it doesn't make difference if we permute it before sorting.
2. Why the observation about $\pi \circ \sigma_n$ gives the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning for question (1) seems perfectly good to me.

For question (2), start with the fact that if $\pi$ is any permuation, then
$\pi \circ \sigma_n$ is uniform over the $n!$ possibilities.

Then note that $\pi_n$ is a permutation. Therefore $\pi_n \circ \sigma_n$ is uniformly distributed over the $n!$ possibilities.

Next observe that $\pi_n \circ \sigma_n$ has the same distribution as $\pi_n$.
In other words, $\pi_n$ has the same distribution as $\pi_n \circ \sigma_n$.
Therefore $\pi_n$ also is uniformly distributed over the $n!$ possibilities.